# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'supabase'. Expected ';' after variable declaration

Tags: javascript, supabase

I am trying to delete a row from the database and when I load the page, the file throws an error saying `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'supabase'. Expected ';' after variable declaration.`

Following is my function code:

```
window.deleteChap = async function deleteChap(x) {

  let chapid = chapids[x];

  Swal.fire({
    title: `Are you sure you want to delete the chapter? This action is irreversible.`,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {

      const { data, error } = await supabase.from('chapters').eq('id', chapid).delete();
      
      if (error) {
        erroralert(error.message);
      } else {
        successalert(`Chapter deleted successfully.`);
      }
    }
  })

}
```

The supabase client has already been initialised this way:

```
let supabase;
$.ajax({
    url: "/keys",
    success: async function( result ) {
  
        result = JSON.parse(result);
  
        supabase = createClient(result.link, result.anon_key);

  }});
```

The javascript file is linked to the html with `<script defer src="/js/dnovelinfo.js" type="module"></script>`

I am not sure why the error is being thrown, even when I haven't interacted with the page (the page was only reloaded to see latest changes)

Comment: The `const { data, error }` line has an `await` but is not in an `async` function.  (And the `deleteChap` function is `async` but doesn't `await` anything.)

Comment: you need to put `async` before the `(result) =>` callback. I'm surprised you're not getting a more informative error message along the lines of "using `await` inside a non-`async` function".

Comment: `supabase` is likely is not defined within that callback scope ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler `supabase` is defined at the top of the file globally

Comment: @ElectricDragon `console.debug(typeof supabase == 'undefined')` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler it returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put the `async` keyword in the function after Swal.fire

It should have been like this: `then( async (result) => {`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('chapters').eq('id', chapid).delete();
```

is not correct, you need to put `.delete()` just after `from('chapters')`, like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('chapters').delete().eq('id', chapid);
```

Comment: Yes I realised that later on

Comment: Ok! I'm glad you found the answer, and thanks for posting it! Have fun with supabase